# After creating new magento account how to open admin panel

Tags: magento2.3.2

[image]

My admin panel was not opening this was giving me to many redirection issue to solve this issue, I had cleared all cache then my admin panel not opening it again redirect to login page.

I also check my account is lock or not but it was unlocked. after that I create new account but how to open admin panel using which link.

Comment: could you please give some screenshot & your di.xml file

Comment: in magento_root\app\etc\env.php change  'host => '127.0.0.1'` to  'host' => 'localhost'`

Comment: my host is allready localhost

Comment: run this command in your cmd(terminal)=> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: After that what will I do to open admin panel

Comment: It not opening admin panel...same login page redirection happen

Comment: Admin panel was not opening it shows only login page

Answer (score 0):

Please check .htaccess file is present at root directory and in pub folder. Also check .htaccess file in media folder.

Comment: .htaccess file is present at pub and root directory and media folder

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my problem after searching some solutions. following link offer solutions could work to solve this problem.

https://www.yireo.com/blog/2010-02-02-unable-to-login-into-the-magento-backend